# i installed python cv but error showing no module named cv2

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
How to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have `python-opencv` installed. Can you try the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Comment: "python-opencv is already the newest version (3.2.0+dfsg-4.1ubuntu0.1)."

Answer (score 0):

seem Python not found opencv module (cv2.so), try:

```
echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth

echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth
```